# Много Фрагментов или много Activity?

Tags: java, android

задаюсь этим вопросом который раз, но не могу понять.

Я хочу создать приложение онлайн магазина и не знаю что использовать много фрагментов или много активити? И да, я знаю, что `Fragment` без `Activity` не живет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно последним модным тенденциям уже пару лет как строго настрого рекомендовано дядей Гуглом использование архитектуры SAA - *Single Activity Application*. В переводе на русский - приложение с одной `Activity`

То есть рекомендуется использование одного/единственного `Activity` с множеством `Fragment`ов, при этом для упрощения навигации между ними можно использовать компоненту [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)

Comment: Спасибо большое)